# Apache installation issue (in windows 7)

Tags: windows, apache, webserver

I want to install Apache Web server,for this I tried in the following way .

Step 1 :

I downloaded Apache Web server from the following [link](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi).

[image]

Step 2:

I installed in the following way.

[image]

click on **Run-->next-->Accepted Terms-->next-->next**

[image]

click on **next-->next-->change..**

[image]

click **OK-->next-->install**. here I am facing the problem I got two screens.

[image]

after completion of 23 seconds,It shows Finish button in main screen, I click on that.

to my conformation,whether it is working or not. I open following URL

```
http://localhost/
```

it's not working.

again for my conformation, I open the following window from my right hand side corner of my system.

[image: Image7]

How can I fix this.

can you suggest me ?

Answer (score 0):

Your port 80 is already in use by another application, you have two options :

- Find & Change the port or Deactivate the application that runs in port 80 (IIS, Skype...)
- Changing the Apache port from 80 to another value.

Comment: can you tell me, where can I change Apache port value.

Comment: You go to your installation folder then you try to find a file called  httpd.conf then you change Listen 80 to another value

Comment: I changed to 81.and I reopen last screen and click on **Exit** button. and click on Start-->Apache Http server 2.0 -->Control Apache Server-> Restart. I am getting the following error `[Fri Jul 05 14:34:42 2013][error] <OS 2> The system cannot find the file specified. : No installed service named "Apache2".
Note the errors or messages above,and press the <ESC> key to exit. 22...` on CMD.

Comment: Check in the 'Services' whether the 'Apache2 service' is created or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is "something" already listening on port 80 of your system, which will prevent Apache from starting. It could be Skype, or a web-server like IIS or Tomcat.

If you open the command-line (cmd.exe) and run `netstat -ona`, and look for the local lines that have port 80 in them (ex: 0.0.0.0:80, 127.0.0.1:80), you can then cross-reference the PID of that "something" with Task Manager's Process list (press Ctrl-Shift-Esc).

Then you can attempt to disable it (if it's a Service) or remove/uninstall it.

A couple of other issues -

1. You are downlading Apache 2.0, which is completly outdated. You should be at least using Apache 2.2.
2. Your Apache download will not come with PHP - you'll only be able to do HTML pages. Nor will it be configured for security, performance, multi-site, etc.

Unless you have a reason not to, try a WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) distribution/package that  has everything already set up for you. The popular free ones that come to mind are [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) and [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/); and there are commercial ones like [Wamp-Developer](https://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper). Ans also a few others not mentioned, that you can find recommended here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

use netstat -bano in an elevated command prompt to see what apps are listening on which ports.

But Usually following applications uses port 80 in windows.

1. IIS
2. World Wide Web Publishing service
3. IIS Admin Service
4. SQL Server Reporting services
5. Web Deployment Agent Service

Stop above applications if running and check!!!